# unfreeze time after rspec examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

On my rspec I call the rails helper method freeze_time

```
before do
  freeze_time
end
```

Do I need to run something to unfreeze Time after the specs

```
after do
  #unfreeze time
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `travel_back` to go back to original time like this.

```rb
after do
  travel_back
end
```

[Here](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers/travel_back) is the documentation of `travel_back`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you have to. Normally I use this with a block so that I don't impact other test example in case i forgot the unfreeze. This is quite common when the spec file is kinda big.

```rb
it 'testing freeze time' do
  freeze_time do
    # do some stuff
  end
  # time is no longer freeze from now on
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually @lacostenycoder `freeze_time` *calls* `travel_to`, with `Time.now`, so that's not quite right.

If you don't want to deal with travelling back, you can use `freeze_time` or `travel_to` with a block though like:

```
freeze_time do
  example.run
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.6/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-freeze_time